# PHP 7.2 native support to connect to MSSQL

Tags: php, sql-server, linux

This [link](http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php) suggests that I should be able to connect to MSSQL from a Linux (Centos) server (PHP 7.2) without any 3rd party installs: 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.odbc-connect.php

Like this (their example):

```
// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver - 
allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 
10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
```

But no luck. I get this error:

```
Connection Failed::[unixODBC][Driver Manager]Data source name not found, and no default driver specified
```

Do I need to install something else? or is there something else I'm not doing? PDO Driver for ODBC (unixODBC) is installed.

Comment: I also see in the php.ini file that it reads: "Note that MySQL and ODBC support is now built in, so no dll is needed for it.
" and extension=php_mssql.dll is enabled by default in php 7.2

Answer (score 0):

Got it working. Here is what I did:

- I updated PHP to 7.2
- Installed ODBC drivers as per this link: 
  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/linux-mac/installing-the-microsoft-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-2017

Changed my connection string from dblib to ODBC:

```
//old    
//$db = new PDO("dblib:host=".HOST.";dbname=".NAME.";charset=utf8", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
//new
$db = new PDO("odbc:Driver={ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server};Server=".HOST.";Database=".NAME.";", "".USER."", "".PASS."");
```

No more FreeTDS or PDO_dblb.